# Animations with multiple Images using FFmpeg or another tools

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

What I have:

- different video templates without logo
- UI where users will select a template from that list
- UI where users can upload their logotype, add mp3 file, text

What should be done:

- new generated video based on this configuration.

What I found:

- I can use ffmpeg and combine it all. But not sure how to make such animations with logo. Maybe there is existing gui.
- I also found https://github.com/inlife/nexrender. But it works with Adobe After Effects and seems like what I need.

Example of result https://www.introbrand.com/logo-opening-mobiles.html

I'm not looking for the ready solution, just a few words - how to go, what to use..
This is absolutely new things for me, so if you could please suggest something or just tell me what's the best way - I'd appreciate this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, I would say this is what you are looking for :https://creatomate.com/blog/video-rendering-with-nodejs-and-ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you so much, analysing this article. Seems like what I'm looking for !